# Need to add a JS file into <head> using a custom module with custom twig template

Tags: theming, hooks

I have created a custom module and created a config page which we need to input the url on that page.

Created a twig template within my custom module:

```
<script src={{ js_file_url }}>test</script>
```

In my .module file

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Add the url to the header section.
 */

/**
 * Implments hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function custom_module_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {

  $js_file_url = \Drupal::config(' custom_module.settings')->get('url');

  $renderable = [
    '#theme' => 'my_template',
    '#test_var' => 'test variable',
  ];

$attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    [
      '#theme'  => 'my_template',
      '#js_file_url'   => $js_file_url,
    ],
  ];  

}


function  custom_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'my_template' => [
      'variables' => ['js_file_url' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

My output:

```
<><script src=http://google.com>test</script></>
```

Expected Output is

```
<script src=http://google.com>test</script>
```

How to get rid of empty tags =>  <>,

By default $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] is adding the '#tag' even if i dont declare it.

Can someone help me, please.

Comment: This seems somewhat dangerous (user defined JS url), but https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2752283

Comment: can we use #theme inside $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] ..?

Comment: I'm wondering if the Twig template makes any sense here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach custom tags to any render array from where it bubbles up into the HTML head. In the following sample I'm adding structured data when a certain block is viewed. `$value` then contains what's being printed between the opening and closing script tag.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_view_system_breadcrumb_block_alter(array &$build, BlockPluginInterface $block) {

  // Get JSON-LD.
  if ($json_ld = \Drupal::service('easy_breadcrumb.structured_data_json_ld')
    ->value()) {

    // Prepare script tag.
    $structured_data = [
      '#tag' => 'script',
      '#attributes' => ['type' => 'application/ld+json'],
      '#value' => $json_ld,
    ];

    // Add script tag.
    $build['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
      $structured_data,
      'easy_breadcrumb_structured_data_json_ld',
    ];
  }
}
```

I hope you get the idea how this can easily be adjusted to get your custom snippet into the head. You can keep your logic in `hook_page_attachments_alter` but then let it look more like in the following snippet. Maybe you don't even need any `#value` at all.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {

  if ($js_file_url = \Drupal::config('MYMODULE.settings')->get('url')) {

    // Prepare script tag.
    $my_script = [
      '#tag' => 'script',
      '#attributes' => ['src' => $js_file_url],
      '#value' => 'test',
    ];

    // Add script tag.
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
      $my_script,
      'MYMODULE_my_script',
    ];
  }
}
```